# open a wepapage inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to open an angular application inside an iFrame from different angular application on form submission. Url of that application(application to be opened) contains # .But iFrame redirects the page to some other Url by removing all part that is appended after #.
Ex: url to be opened : http://localhost:8080/tempApp/dist/#/web/properties?objIndex=1234
    url loaded in iFrame: http://localhost:8080/tempApp/dist/?objIndex=1234
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a pipe for that and use DomSanitizer

for example

```
import { MyApp, SafePipe } from './myapp.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SafePipe
  ],
```

Create pipe in your app

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, ElementRef, PipeTransform, Pipe, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapp.component.css']
})

export class MyApp {
  title = 'app';
  myiframe: string = "your_url_here"
}
```

In your html

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" [src]="myiframe | safe">
</iframe>
```